# How to crop some part of sprite?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a game like tap tap ants(https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tap-tap-ants/id348839552?mt=8) in iPhone.

I want to crop some portion of sprite. when an ant touches cake sprite, some portion of cake disappear. I researched a lot but could not find any solution.

Plz help

Comment: i think you need two part of object like fruit Ninja game.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spritesheets in the form of CCSpriteBatchNode to set a display frame on a sprite.  As done so below.  This allows you to select a boxed region of the spritesheet to be displayed.

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *caveSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"cavey_ss3.png"];
[self addChild:caveSheet];
CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"somethingUnimportant.png"];

CCSpriteFrame *frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:caveSheet.texture rect:CGRectMake(0,0,300,300)];   
//(x-start, y-start, width, height)


[player setDisplayFrame:frame];
```

Or if you want something like a notch in the corner of the image gone, then you could set up two sprites working off the same CCSpriteBatchNode, with different frames, something like in the picture below.

[image]

In this example the frames would be something like this

sprite1 has CGRectMake(0,10,10,40)

sprite 2 has CGRectMake(10,0,20,50)

but ofcourse you would have to position the sprites accordingly aswell.

Answer (score 0):

In the very latest version of cocos2d-iphone, they added a class called CCClippingNode. You can use it to clip (show only part of) your node and its contents.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.1.0/interface_c_c_clipping_node.html