# crop a sprite image inside cocos2dx android?

Tags: android, image, sprite, cocos2d-x

In my app, there is a scene in which when the user touches on the eat button, i want my candy to start disappearing from top. To be specific, on each button click, I want to remove 10% of the candy image from the top be removed.
Any help?

Comment: There are several approaches: CCClippingNode, CCRenderTexture.
See Test Project of cocos2d-x for details.

Comment: I found this solution but this is for iphone. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697592/how-to-crop-some-part-of-sprite). This is my code.
`CCSpriteBatchNode* cavesheet=CCSpriteBatchNode::create(candy.c_str());
this->addChild(cavesheet);
CCSpriteFrame *frame = CCSpriteFrame::createWithTexture(cavesheet->getTexture(),CCRect(0,0,480,heigth*0.9));
FinalScreen::cottoncandy->setDisplayFrame(frame);`

Comment: What i am trying to do is that each time this line of code runs, I want to remove 10% of the image from the top and keep reducing it but weird things happen like the position changes and i dont know what else. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use progress bar with vertical direction. on each tap, set the percentage of progress sprite. it will be visualised as

Comment: A detailed help is available [here](http://www.aeonphyxius.com/2013/06/how-to-use-a-progress-bar-in-cocos2d-x-and-c/)

Answer (score 0):

Or You can do it other way round make several images of candy each 10% less than the previous one. Then on the button press replace the image with 10% lesser image.

Regards,
Dushyant.

Comment: is there any way to do this automatically? any software? becz there are 9 different types of candy

Comment: According to my knowledge, You have to do this manually using photoshop,this way you have full control over your images the way you want them to look.